# My script seems to get stuck once N >> 1

Tags: python, arrays

## Edit :

So I let the code run for 70 hours and it did not return. Thus I stick to my point, it does get stuck on something, fails silently and let the bash hanging. From the time increase compared to the relatively small jump between N1 and N2, it's not something a O(N) -> O(N²) can explain.

(input going from N to 2N implies an execution time going from N² to 4N², so it should only take 4 time more. Not returning after hours for 2N while finishing in 15 minutes max for N means something fails)

Accepted solution works very well until it reaches (instantly) a very clean memory overflow.

> $ py so_mysan.py 400000000 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "so_mysan.py", line 36, in 
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))   File "so_mysan.py", line 8, in main
>       ordering = list(range(N)) MemoryError

Thank you for your time.

## /edit

```
import sys
import numpy as np 
from random import randint

def main(arguments):
    N = int(sys.argv[1])
    # definissons notre ligne de maison : 
    houses = [0]*N
    emptySlot = list(range(0,N)) 
    # counter = 1 
    while (len(emptySlot)>0):
        # on prend une maison vide possiblement habitable par un mysanthrope, au hasard. 
        empt = randint(0, len(emptySlot)-1)
        houses[emptySlot[empt]] = 1
        # on enlève cette maison de notre liste de possibilité 
        # et éventuellement les maisons adjacentes si elles y étaient
        temp = emptySlot[empt]
        del emptySlot[empt]
        # on essaye d'enlever les autres si existes plus efficacement : 
        if (0<=empt and empt<len(emptySlot) and emptySlot[empt] == temp+1):
            del emptySlot[empt] # comme on a viré l'index empt, ça décale.
        if (empt-1 >= 0 and emptySlot[empt-1] == temp-1):
            del emptySlot[empt-1] # pour l'inférieur, cela ne change rien

    occupancyRate = sum(houses) / N
    print(occupancyRate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

I guess it's something to do with the array size but my resources monitoring does not show CPU or RAM going through the roof. It runs fine up to N = 4.10^6

I don't think multi threading is possible or worth since it's just one array getting manipulated.

What can I do to optimize it ?

How to debug such a script ? I need to know if it's 'stuck' or just taking an incredible amount of time.

Thanks

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve? I do not understand French and cannot follow the comments.

Comment: Could you better explain what you are trying to accomplish? How have you tried debugging it? If you uncomment one of those print() functions in the loop you can easily find whether it got stuck or not.

Comment: What happens for N = 3.99 million?

Comment: @JohanL The code is pretty much self explanatory, the comment are written to myself when I am thinking about what I am trying to do before actually coding it. I am not so sure I am able to explain it better in english than in the code. You got N*[0] that you will try to fill one by one randomly respecting the following rule : no filling in slot x if slot x-1 and x+1 are already filled. So at best, you can have 0.5 filling rate and at worst 1/3. What's the filled slots / total slot ratio when N tends to infinity ? 
I used a EmptySlot tracking array which I found is a good solution.

Comment: @AlexP. See previous comment for context, although, again, I am not sure it's needed here, the code works fine enough for me at lowish N. 
print() is nice and was used to make it work, sadly once you reach N=10^6, the printing process to the screen destroys the performance and it takes forever. I don't know how to debug that. I used VSCode with python extension if it helps. Usually, the terminal print any error making the script crash.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't know I am not gonna run it for every value between 3.10^6 and 4.10^6. It takes several minutes already at 3.10^6 
Maybe something is overflowing?

Comment: The code works fine for smaller `N` but not for bigger, since it is highly inefficient in terms of operations. That is not apparent at smaller `N` values. However, given what you try to achieve, there are much more effeicent ways to do it. To give you a good soluiton, it is necessary to understand you use case in some more detail. That is the reason for us wondering what you try to achieve.

Comment: @JohanL please tell me which are the highly inefficient steps, I will search how to get rid of them myself. Since I don't know python, I have no idea which step might be expensive to compute. I told you everything I am trying to do. there is no other files, other code, everything is here and all this code does is printing a number at the end :D

There is no point for me if you give me the whole "good solution", I want to think more by myself.

Comment: So there is nothing special about 4x10^6 as the title suggests.

Comment: @mkrieger1 indeed, I now see that this phrasing was poor. My bad. Is it better with "once N >> 1" ?

Comment: If it turns out to be an algorithm efficiency problem, you better ask your question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) But you have to provide a description, what the program does, and a sample input/output there as well.

Comment: To be honest @Piinthesky, the more I think about it, the less it seems plausible that it's an efficiency problem. Something must overflow between 3.10^6 and 4.10^6 . I see no reason for the script to suddenly get stuck while it finishes in a few minutes at 3.10^6. I will give it a go at Code Review. As anyone try to run it here ?

Comment: Can you show some measurements of run time vs. input size (N), and state what run time behaviour you did expect and what you observe instead?

Comment: [Cross posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/186913/84718) to Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be on code review, since it is a complexity issue, but then again, the algorithm as written, does not work for large `N`:s so I'll persent an alternative approach.

Deleting element in the middle of a list is likely to lead to very many (and costly) memory operations. It is much better to try to keep them to a minimum by first prepare a (random) list of elements and then access them in a linear fashion. There is a very nifty function called `random.shuffle` that can be used for generating a random list:

```
import random

N = 10000000

ordering = list(range(N))
random.shuffle(ordering)

houses = [0]*N

for elem in ordering:
    if (elem == 0 or houses[elem-1] == 0) and (elem == N-1 or houses[elem+1] == 0):
        houses[elem] = 1

occupancyRate = sum(houses) / N
print(occupancyRate)
```

In this code a random element order is generated first (using `random.shuffle`) then this random list is accessed linearly. I also do not delete any elements while goin through the list, as there is little or no gain in that since the maximum memory consumption will still be the same.

This is likely to give you much better run times and allows you to handle much bigger lists. However, the algorithm is still linear in both time and memory consumption, so you will hit a roof for this one as well.

Comment: thank you for your time! & sorry I could not go back to this earlier. See my edit for more details.

Comment: And I am grateful that you show me that trick to randomize only once and efficiently, I am sure I will be able to use it again.